# Git reset current rebase

Tags: git, rebase

I've been doing a rebase. I've worked on fixing some conflicts but I've ended up going in the wrong direction and now I just want to start again fixing these conflicts.

I'd like to reset the rebase, so that I'm still rebasing the current commit but the working copy has been reset to when the commit was flagged up with conflicts in the first place.

How can I reset a rebase on the current commit?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you just want to redo a merge for a specific file, all you need to do is:

```
git checkout -m <file>
```

If you want to redo the whole commit, here's how I do it (there's probably a better way of doing this):

1. There's a conflict during the rebase
2. I mess up the conflict resolution
3. I run a `git status` which, as of Git 2.0.0, gives me something like this (**only if you are doing an interactive rebase**):

   ```
   interactive rebase in progress; onto 14ed389
   Last command done (1 command done):
      pick db2511c Modify file
   Next command to do (1 remaining command):
      pick d1c2037 Modify file one more time
     (use "git rebase --edit-todo" to view and edit)
   You are currently rebasing branch 'other' on '14ed389'.
     (fix conflicts and then run "git rebase --continue")
     (use "git rebase --skip" to skip this patch)
     (use "git rebase --abort" to check out the original branch)

   Unmerged paths:
     (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
     (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

           both modified:   file.txt
   ```
4. I copy the line for the command the rebase is currently executing: `pick db2511c Modify file`
5. I run `git rebase --edit-todo` and paste the line onto the top of the file
6. I run `git rebase --skip`

Answer (score 24):

If you are in between your rebase, you can do

```
git rebase --abort
```

Comment: That would abort the whole rebase, instead of just rebasing this one commit.

Answer (score 17):

First, clear the mess:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Then, cherry-pick the commit you are currently rebasing:

```
git cherry-pick -n `git rev-parse REBASE_HEAD`
```

That's it. As usual, you will be able to continue the rebase after fixing  conflicts.

Comment: This basically allows you to restart the current rebase stage, awesome!

Answer (score 2):

If you do this often (like I do ), you can make a useful git alias (based off [Pierre’s elegant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53141807/625710))

```
[alias]
    # Restart the current rebase step if you accidentally messed it up
    # SEE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53141807/625710
    restart-rebase-step = !git reset --hard HEAD && git cherry-pick -n `git rev-parse REBASE_HEAD`
```

You can then call it from the command line:

```bash
git restart-rebase-step
```

Answer (score 0):

If You have had multiple commits editing same files on both branches and, during rebasing decided that want to preserve some work, not drop all changes already made (`git rebase --abort`) then I guess You'll need to look into directory `.git/rebase-apply` and check `patch` file. It contains all changes made during rebasing. You'd manually apply this patch after doing `git rebase --abort`.

Answer (score 0):

To use [elstgav resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73809112/8604967) without the alias, first do the reset:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Then get the SHA1 of the rebase:

```
rev-parse REBASE_HEAD
b10b228e263dfa223221036fa17506445a101f0f // this is the SHA1 value
```

After that, use the SHA1 value with the `cherry-pick` command:

```
git cherry-pick -n b10b228e263dfa223221036fa17506445a101f0f
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add some refinements to [Pierre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53141807/625710):

1. You don't have to specify `HEAD` as an argument to reset. It's used by default. So it's okay to run:

   ```
   git reset --hard
   ```

   There is a problem with this command though. It changes `ORIG_HEAD` to last successfully rebased commit. As a consequence it breaks a possibility to [rewind unsatisfactory rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51496983/265374) with:

   ```
   git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD
   ```

   Hence it may be preferred to use `git checkout -f` instead of `git reset --hard`. The `checkout -f` command will discard all the changes as compared to `HEAD` (last rebased commit) and will leave `ORIG_HEAD` untouched. Same here, `HEAD` argument is optional:

   ```
   git checkout -f
   ```
2. There is no need to use `git rev-parse` to convert `REBASE_HEAD` to commit id. It's done by `git cherry-pick` automatically. So it's okay to run:

   ```
   git cherry-pick -n REBASE_HEAD
   ```