# Delete branch after checkout from the master

Tags: git

I check out a branch named `FNB-90` from the master. In the branch `FNB-90`, I made 2 add, commits and push them to the remote. Then,  check out another branch named `FNB-90-CHILD` from the `FNB-90`.

a. Now, if in the branch `FNB-90`, I commend:

```
$ git fetch  # will fetch the latest changes on the remote
$ git reset --hard origin/master # will set your local branch to match the representation of the remote just pulled down.
```

will the `FNB-90` revert back to the original state that I have checked out? If not, then how to do that?

b. If I delete the branch `FNB-90` with the commend,

```
$ git branch -d FNB-90
$ git push origin --delete FNB-90
```

What will happen to the branch `FNB-90-CHILD` i.e. will it become a direct branch of the `master`?

Comment: Branches in git are 'pointers to a "head" node in a *particular* DAG'. Insofar, two different branch names are not related - deleting a name to a commit (see previous) does not affect any other names to that commit or other commits.

Comment: Whats the DAG and can you write a brief answer if time permits? Specially, I need to know how to revert back the `FNB-90` to the original state after the add, commit and push(s)

Comment: DAG stands for [Directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) - basically, no commit can ever be an ancestor (or a descendant) of itself.

Comment: To put back FNB-90 to the original state, force it (`branch -f`) to the appropriate commit where it "should" be; changing remote branches might upset others, but.. The [`reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) is usually handy to see where things came from if they were accidentally moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer: a**

> will the FNB-90 revert back to the original state that I have checked out?

Yes, now `origin/master` and local `FNB-90` are have same commit history. If you want to update `origin/FNB-90` then you have to do `force push`.

**N.B.** Force push will replace the history of `origin/FNB-90` with the history of local FNB-90.

```
$ git fetch
$ git checkout FNB-90
$ git reset --hard origin/master

$ git push -f origin FNB-90
```

Now, `origin/master` = `origin/FNB-90` = `local FNB-90` are in same state.

Also, `FNB-90-CHILD` has no effect for this. (history is same as before)

---

**Answer: b**

if you delete the branch `FNB-90` from local and remote it will have no effect on `FNB-90-CHILD`. A branch (HEAD) just a pointer to a commit. If we delete a branch, it deletes the branch's pointer but commit exists yet.

Answer (score 1):

> will the FNB-90 revert back to the original state that I have checked out?

Yes, provided master did not have commits done locally compared to origin/master.
To be sure to revert, look for the `checkout FNB-90` event in the **[reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)**, as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41049867/6309).

Note that if you did pushed `FNB-90` before, you will have to do a `git push --force` in order to propagate that reset: make sure your colleagues are aware of that (they will have to reset their own `FNB-90` branch)