# git history screwed up

Tags: git, rebase, squash, git-squash

I was trying to do rebase to combine the commits into one single commit, but I ended up writing more commits and now its all screwed up big time.

Here is the tree:
on running `git status`, I get

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Last commands done (5 commands done):
   pick 49147e5 squash
   pick 2c48387 Commit 
  (see more in file .git/rebase-merge/done)
Next commands to do (13 remaining commands):
   pick fddd4c7 commit 
   pick 5f01f80 commit 
  (use "git rebase --edit-todo" to view and edit)
You are currently editing a commit while rebasing branch 'master' on '1550461'.
  (use "git commit --amend" to amend the current commit)
  (use "git rebase --continue" once you are satisfied with your changes)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

On running `git log --oneline`, I am getting:

```
Merge branch 'master' of .....
49147e5 squash
0310431 commit 4 which was PR
d4be53f commit 6
ea24a2d commit 5
1550461 commit 3
fc8115a commit 2
212138a commit 1
72d8fff Merge pull request #64 from branch 1
c5ad199 commit 14
2a6ceaf commit 13
6660dbf commit 12
b6c863e commit 11
88788e6 commit 10
5bbe8a7 commit 9
9731810 commit 8
1e4ac6b commit 7
ce3817c Merge branch 'master' of .... into branch 1
ec4c3e9 commit 6
5b8900b commit 5
d10eec9 commit 4 which was PR
5f01f80 commit 3
fddd4c7 commit 2
02ebbc8 Merge branch 'master' of ....into branch 1
3995cf2 pr changes v2
2c48387 commit 1
```

How I screwed up:
From `72d8fff`, I did `git rebase -i HEAD~7 or 8`, `git pull`, then `git push`. I wanted to `squash` all commits after `d10eec9` into one single commit but I think I ended up writing on top of HEAD.

I was thinking to do `git reset --hard 72d8fff` then `git push origin HEAD --force` which will atleast bring me back to where I started.
Please save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> bring me back to where I started.

Locally, you might have a look at [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog), which will list the tips of branches and other references were updated in the local repository.

You will find there what HEAD refered to *before* your rebase.
If you `reset --hard` to that commit, you will be back to before the rebase.
You can also compare that commit with (if you have not done any other rebase) [`ORIG_HEAD` and reset on that commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51496983/6309).

The idea remains: restore first locally your history, then squash again your last commits (this time, [without rebase, but using `git reset --soft`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61171280/6309)), and force push once the state of your local repository is satisfactory.

Comment: I tried `rebase` on different branches for trial and that is why it is annoying to see `git reflog`. Hence, I was thinking to simply do `git reset --hard 72d8fff` after that `git reset --soft HEAD~9` [here I am confused if I should do HEAD~8] then `git commit` and then `git push -f`. Note this is master branch so I am scared.

Comment: @amyJ Try it locally first: it the result is correct, then you can push. Don't  push if you are not sure.

Comment: ok, so when I do `git reset --hard 72d8fff`, I am getting to the previous commit from where I started the `rebase`. Now, when I do `git reset --soft HEAD~1`, all the commits from `[5b8900b, 72d8fff]` are gone. It is probably because I made those changes on the feature branch and then I merged to `master` and the git is pointing to the previous `HEAD`. When I do `git commit -v` the changes are looking fine. My only concern is should I abort the `rebase` first before I do anything? The messages posted in the question is still there

Comment: Yes, before any reset, I would first abort the current rebase, or quit it as a last resort (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41363262/6309)